# Firefox "new tab" notification sound

Tags: firefox

I surf in fullscreen-mode and never know if a new tab has opened, because i hide the tab-bar and firefox does not give any notification about new tab creation. Is there a lightweight way to get newtab notification (sound) ?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Noise](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noise/) firefox addon:

> The Noise Firefox add-on can play sounds for more than 20 browser events such as when **opening a new tab** or when a popup has been blocked. You have the option to specify a different sound of your choosing for each action and you can also create your own sound events.

Comment: There seems to be no "NewTab" (etc) event in Firefox that fires when you open links in new tabs. So the Noise addon sadly does not work for my case.